What this sentence mean here: 「屁しよ思たら漏れたわって」
This manga is usually in 関西弁 but i think i cannot finally understand that little sentence very well


I think it looks more like しよ(う) rather than しょ

The same sentence in standard Japanese, with nothing omitted, would be:

屁をしようと思ったら、漏れた(よ)。
I tried to fart, and then [it] leaked (i.e., I ended up sharting).


を has been omitted
しよう has been contracted to しよ
と has been omitted
思ったら has been contracted to 思たら

